# Не подключается зависимость jsp

Tags: java, java-ee, maven

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet.jsp/javax.servlet.jsp-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Изучаю Java EE. Пишу первое простое приложение. Столкнулся с проблемой. Не удаётся подключить зависимость в Maven проект. groupId, adrtifactId, version выделяет красным цветом. Подскажите, что нужно проверить? С чем связана эта ошибка?

Answer (score 0):

Это очень странно, но проблему решил реимпорт Maven